# I have two servers I want to use second one as secondary server what should I do?

Tags: networking, 20.04

I have two ubuntu20.04 servers, I want the second server as a secondary server if one is down the second one automatically up's, what should I do

Comment: You should probably read up on [load balancing](https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/load-balancing/). However, this type of question is not well suited for this site, as it requires a specific question with specific answers. This topic is probably too open-ended.

Comment: Automatic failover generally requires a third server of some sort that monitors and coordinates. That said, it’s also important to know what is being failed over. Databases are a bit more complicated to configure than a simple web server. Mail servers can be even more complex …

Comment: Some hosting/DNS companies (like CloudFlare) also provide load balancing/failover services.. But still, this has nothing to do with Ubuntu itself.